# SAS proc contents

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am trying to list content of sas library `Sasuser` with standard sas 9 setup. From explorer, the library contains Table and catalogs. I am wondering what went wrong. Plus I am able to run `proc contents` on `Sashelp.__all__` and individual table under Sasuser like Sasuser.Mysales2. So what do I need to do to make it work. thanks

proc contents data=Sasuser._all__ ;

/*ERROR: File SASUSER._ALL__.DATA does not exist.
*/

Answer (score 3):

You were simply missing an underscore.

```
proc contents data=Sasuser._all_ ;run;
```

Cheers